# How to return single row when there is match between 2 source tables(left outer join query) in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have below tables in BigQuery

Source Table:

```
Col1,Col2
1,'S1'
1,'S2'
2,'S3'
```

Lookup Table:

```
Col1,Col2
1,'L1'
1,'L1'
2,'L2'
```

I need to get any row from Lookup table for each incoming row from source if there is match for col1

Expected Result:

```
Col1, Col2
1,L1
1,L1
2,L2
```

Tried below Query:

```
SELECT T.Col1, T.Col2 FROM ((select PM_ALookup_1.Col1, PM_ALookup_1.Col2,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PM_ALookup_1.Col1 ORDER BY PM_ALookup_1.Col1) as rownum FROM TEST.SOURCE LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST.LOOKUP PM_ALookup_1 ON (PM_ALookup_1.Col1 = SOURCE.Col1  AND PM_ALookup_1.Col1 = SOURCE.Col1))) as T where T.rownum=1
```

But it returns below result:
Col1,Col2
1,L1
2,L2

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST.LOOKUP
WHERE Col1 IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Col1 FROM TEST.SOURCE
)
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. I am looking for some more modification in the query, The condition can be multiple columns. Let's say Source table has Col1,Col2,Col3.. and Lookup table has Col1,COl2,Col3..                                                                                                          SELECT l.COL1,l.COl2,l.Col3 FROM Catallica.Source1 s left outer join (SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM Catallica.Lookup1 l where l.Col1=Source1.Col1 and l.Col2=Source1.Col2) . This throws an error saying Source1 is invalid. How can i modify this query to make it work?

Comment: your question is answered as it is. if you have new question(s) - please post them as new question with all relevant details